# Regex to add missing space after comma before argument in functions (to meet coding guidelines)

Tags: regex

there is an open source php project i would like to contribute by reducing some coding guidline violations. as there are about 5000 violations for a specific sniff i guess it would be appropriate to use some regex.

the coding guidline rule is called "FunctionCallArgumentSpacingNoSpaceAfterComma". this means that all arguemts should be separated by a comma followed by a space.

these example snippets violate this rule:

```
$this->message('About', 'Warning, very important!', $this->securityRisk().$this->alterPasswordForm(),2);
$sFiles = t3lib_div::getFilesInDir(PATH_typo3conf,'sql',1,1);
if (!strstr(implode(',',$sFiles).',', '/database.sql,')) {
```

can anybody help in creating a useful regex to fix these coding guidline violations? i tried some hours but i am unfortunately not capable to solve this on my own.

Comment: Had it occurred to you that, if it were possible to do this with a simple regex, someone would have done so already?

Comment: Is there a php IDE that can do this?

Comment: netbeans can do this via autoformatting, but as far as i experienced it is not able to ONLY do this specific autoformatting. so i would mess up some other stuff instead.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would try would be something like this:

```
sed 's/,\([^ ]\)/, \1/g' someFile.php
```

Replace commas followed by non-spaces with a comma, a space, and the character that *WAS* after the comma.

After thinking about it for a split-second, that might kinda work.

But there must be multiple things I'm not thinking of...

Comment: See the third example.  What happens with the `','` `char` literals?

Comment: Mabye the above regex combined with some more work could eventually get the job done.  For example you could find all the char literals and change the comma to something else temporarily... Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

You can't safely/reliably do this with a regex.  You can't even reliably skip past string literals in some languages (contemplate Perl's `q` syntax; especially how it works with what it considers to be "bracketing" characters).  And even ignoring those, you get into trouble if you have multiple languages in the codebase (there being subtle differences between string/character literals in, say, PHP, Java, and Perl).